# Could not resolve host: bitbucket.org

Tags: git, npm, server, bitbucket

There was some space issue on my ubuntu server. I freed up the space and later tried to do `git pull`. I am getting an error like

```
$ git pull
fatal: unable to access 'https://<user>@bitbucket.org/<repo>.git/': Could not resolve host: bitbucket.org
```

I have ran the below commands:

```
git remote -v
```

Output: (as expected)

```
origin  https://<user>@bitbucket.org/<repo>.git (fetch)
origin  https://<user>@bitbucket.org/<repo>.git (push)
```

Have also tried by removing the origin and setting it again by:

```
git remote rm origin
git remote add origin https://user@bitbucket.org/user/ex.git
```

Also `npm install` isn't working, it is stuck. Checked my internet connection as well but no luck in any case. Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

`Could not resolve host` is a DNS issue. You should review your DNS configuration in your Network Settings which will depend on your OS. If your local DNS cache or ISP's DNS is failing, you might want to configure a backup public DNS server (Ex: Google: 8.8.8.8, Cloudfare: 1.1.1.1).